# Storyboard Xcode Navigationbar lost (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

in my storyboard i have a navigation controller connected with a table view controller. By clicking on a cell it opens another view controller. This view controller i added in the storyboard and gave them an identifier. In the view controller class of the table view controller i go to the view controller with

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(overviewTeams, animated: true)
```

But when the controller view is openend there is no top navigation bar. Do I have to connect it in the storyboard also?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just make a segue from the cell to the next controller, then you don't need any code to perform the segue? You shouldn't have to do anything to get the navigation bar to show.

Comment: the push seque is deprecated or not?

Comment: You can still use a push even though it's depreciated, but if you're using size classes, then you would use Show instead.